# how to make this SVG wave animation smooth. in the end it doesn't run smooth

Tags: html, css, svg

[open Codepen Code for better uderstanding](https://codepen.io/aldrinbright/pen/gOXbBjK)

> how to make this SVG wave animation smooth. In the end it doesn't run smooth
> it should not look like its starting over again

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::after,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wave-Bg {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wave1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 200%;
  fill: rgb(18, 195, 201);
  animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>SVG Animation</h1>
<div class="wave-Bg">
  <svg class="wave1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120">
    <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

> how to make this SVG wave animation smooth. In the end, it doesn't run
> smooth, it starts over again.

Comment: You have to draw your wave and set your transform so that the wave's height is the same at the start transform as it is at the end transform. You're not doing this so it doesn't look continuous.

Comment: You need to do as @MichaelMullany has said, but then you'll need to do something like have two copies one after the other and translate just halfway in each animation iteration otherwise you'll get a blank space between waves.